# Trying to display a variable in a for loop inside of razor with C#/Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to loop through a set of numbers and display them on a scorecard.  If I step through the code, the variable returns the correct values, I just can't get them to display.

```
    @foreach (var g in Model)
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<tr>"))
            int grossScore = 0;

            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", g.PlayerName))
        for (int s = 0; s < 18; s++)
        {
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>"));

            int holescore = 0;
            var bretak = @g.Scores.Take(1).Skip(s).FirstOrDefault();
            var werwee = @g.Scores.Where(b => b.Hole == s + 1).Select(i => i.Score).FirstOrDefault();
            //if (bretak.Score > 0)
            //{
            //    holescore = bretak.Score;
            //}

            holescore = werwee;

            Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}", holescore));
            //@Html.ToString(holescore);
            //Html.Raw(holescore);
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>" + @holescore + "</td>"));
            grossScore = grossScore + holescore;

            @Html.Raw(string.Format("</td>"));
        }
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", grossScore))

            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td align=\"center\"> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs editBtn\" data-player-id=\"'{0}'\">Edit </button></td>", g.GameId))
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs deleteBtn\" data-player-id=\"'{0}'\">Delete </button></td>", g.GameId)) 
        @Html.Raw("</tr>")
     }
```

Player name displays correctly and the grossscore variable calculates and displays correctly.  I get the correct number of boxes from inside the loop but holescore won't display.  Sorry that it may look a little messy but I left some of the code in to show the some of the things I have tried.

Comment: `holescore` is set via `holescore = werwee;` so make sure that `werwee`is not `null`

Comment: It is null after the 4th hole but holes 1-4 all have valid data.

Comment: So use `<text>@holescore</text>` if you want to display it.

Comment: Thank you, that works!  As Munzer said, I didn't grasp what html.raw was doing.  Another question though...  Your addition works, but now my website won't load if I hit debug.  It will sit on a blank screen until I hit <F5> then will come up and work.

Comment: All that code can be simply replaced with `@foreach (var player in Model) { <tr> <td>player.PlayerName</td> @foreach(var hole in player.Scores){ <td>@hole.Score</td> } <td>@player.Scores.Sum(x => x.Score)</td> </tr> }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstood html.Raw, it is used to decode string into html string, not for outputting , for output you simply type 
so instead of something like this

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>" + @holescore + "</td>"));
```

just use this

```
<td> @holescore</td>
```

I suggest you going through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) to get a clearer picture as I assume you didn't based on your code above.

Comment: Thank you as well.  Your code also works, but does the same thing I mentioned above.   My website won't load if I hit debug. It will sit on a blank screen until I hit <F5> then will come up and work.  The funny thing about the <td> is that there is a squiggly line under it that says "Element 'td' cannot be nested inside element 'table'.  The td element represents a data cell in a table."  Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: you should remove html.raw, it is unnecessary, I think you are missing your tr tag that's why you are getting that message. double check your `<tr>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Chris after looking at your code below statement needs @ at start.

```
Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}", holescore));
```

But below statement should have displayed the score.Have you tried this statement or its just for info

```
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<td>" + @holescore + "</td>"));
```

Either use above statement or add @ at start of the first statement